What should I do with academic misconduct of my advisor?
My PhD advisor shared research proposal materials with us that he has reviewed as a grant panelist. He told us feel free to read whenever we have time and explore these ideas. I don't feel comfortable about that, but I don't know how to say no. What should I do?

What did your advisor say when you brought this up with him? That might shed useful light on the situation.

Which jurisdiction? Do you have evidence? Witnesses? What happens to you if your advisor is fired? These things need to be taken into account.

This is certainly unethical, but it does not sound like he is actively telling you that you need to do this. Certainly "feel free to read whenever you have time" is far from what I imagined when I read "he asked us to explore these ideas". It seems like the simplest response is to do nothing, or to say that you are not comfortable with this, and perhaps to encourage your fellow students to do the same.

Is your advisor asking you to explore specific proposed ideas, or are they excited about certain topical areas which the proposals have (re)introduced to them? I know I have certainly been excited about certain (sub)topical areas and how they align with my groups research after sitting on panels. Though I would certainly never take any proposed work, the requisite background reading and discussion definitely sparked ideas. Similarly to going to a good conference. Academic misconduct is a VERY serious accusation, I would try to understand exactly what your advisor wants before doing anything.

As he mentioned "in a drawer", which makes it sound like there's a lot of them: Are these current proposals undergoing evaluation ? Or are these approved ones that could (if you knew were to look) possibly be found in another way ?

I thought you are a tenured professor. Now a PhD student?

You can delete "as a tenured professor" from the answer that @BryanKrause links to, but the first version is still visible. I think some greater honesty on this question or on that answer would be welcome.

@Aruralreader, fyi, there are users "scientist" and "Scientist", and I think you intend to refer to the lowercase one...

@paulgarrett, thank you, my mistake. I’m delete my comment.

You are certainly right in feeling uncomfortable: Your advisor is violating confidentiality just by giving you access to the submissions. There are very strict rules and the old possibility to ask students for reviews or help with reviews is now no longer permitted without explicit permission by the conference chair / journal editor. Grant application by nature are more sensitive. You can safely assume that no permission has been given since your advisor would have mentioned this. It seems your advisor is somewhat oblivious to the breach of rules of conduct rather than willingly misbehaving.
Reviewing grants has one big benefit, which is knowing what other people are looking at, which naturally stimulate one's own creativity. The idea that we can forget a paper or grant application we reviewed is just a moral abstraction that cannot be completely implemented in reality. However, as reviewers, we are supposed to pretend that we forget everything in the review material that is not already published.
The best way for you, which might come at costs to you, is to contact the ombudsman of the granting institution. Because of the possibility of retaliation, you can use your private email account and approach them, asking what to do. If there is not ombudsman, just write to anyone in charge and ask for advice. Since it will be your word against your advisor's, your advisor will presumably receive just a warning that this is not to be done, but your advisor can then also feel wronged by you because your advisor was trying to be helpful to your career. Even if the advisor cannot identify you, this would be bad for the atmosphere in the group.
I do not think that you are in any danger here, other than having an advisor who in the future might be sanctioned (which could be a big deal for your own research career). If this is not a single failure of judgment, then you probably should definitely look for a different advisor. People who play loose with other peoples' ideas might find it suddenly difficult to maintain collaborations, and this has an effect on their students as well. Against your will you have be made a potential beneficiary of improper behavior, and you have not acted immorally. It just sometimes happens that we are innocent beneficiaries of somebody else's wrong doing without the possibility to undo damage.

Whatever you decide to do, this has given you information about how your advisor operates. Part of his job is to teach you academic norms and ethics, and he is teaching you unethical behaviour. Keep an eye out for other unethical behaviour from him, and be aware that you may be learning a warped view of what is acceptable from him.
You could try saying "I want to make sure I've understood what you were asking us to do with the grant proposals, because I thought those would be confidential. Could you clarify what we are and aren't allowed to do with that information?" I would be able to say something like this to my advisor (although I doubt they'd do this in the first place), but I know other PhD students who couldn't say something like that without risking retaliation. If you do try this, make sure you are treating it as if you are genuinely asking them to clarify. There is a risk of coming off as passive aggressive, so I wouldn't do this if you're not confident.
There are risks to not saying anything. Quietly ignoring the situation is an option, but even if you don't look at the proposals yourself, you may end up involved in research built off plagiarised ideas. I think it's unlikely to majorly blow up in your face, but if your advisor pursues this, someone who wrote one of those grant proposals might see their ideas in a paper from your group with you in the co-authors and suspect what happened.
If there's another academic at your university that you trust, you could quietly ask them for advice. If you're in the UK and you're a member of UCU, you can also contact your local branch for advice. They will also be able to support you if the situation escalates in some way. You need to be a member before whatever situation you need support with happens, so if you're not a member now would be a good time to join in case you get dragged into an academic misconduct dispute later.
